# Project with path ':react-native-community_checkbox' could not be found in project ':app'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I tried to add "@react-native-community/checkbox" to my React-Native project. When i run command "react-native run-ios" everything works fine but when i try to run "react-native run-android" i got the error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script '/Users/../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle'
>   line: 124
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. Project with path ':react-native-community_checkbox' could not be
>   found in project ':app'.

in settings.gradle linking look like

> include ':@react-native-community_checkbox'
> project(':@react-native-community_checkbox').projectDir = new
> File(rootProject.projectDir,
> '../node_modules/@react-native-community/checkbox/android')

I stuck this problem for 3 days can anyone give any advice pls?

Comment: remove this line from gradle and install again hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall library and delete build folder and app cache
Then try it again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).